# simple_navigation gem and rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

routes.rb

```
PASFramework::Application.routes.draw do |map|

  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :index
      get :edit
      post :update
      get :show
  end
 end

  root :to => 'users#index'

end
```

==================================================================
    navigation.rb

```
# Configures your navigation

SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :users, 'Welcome User', root_path do |users|
      users.item :edit, 'Edit Profile', edit_users_path
    end
  end
```

end

==================================================================

User_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    user = current_facebook_user.fetch
    @u = User.find_by_facebook_id(user.id)
    if @u.nil?
      @u = User.find_or_create_by_facebook_id(user.id)
      @u.update_attributes( :first_name => current_facebook_user.first_name,
                        :last_name => current_facebook_user.last_name )
      gflash :notice => "Welcome, #{current_facebook_user.name} "
    else
      gflash :notice => "Welcome back, #{current_facebook_user.first_name} #{current_facebook_user.last_name}"
    end
    return

    rescue Exception
      logger.info "Problem"
      logger.error($!)
      top_redirect_to auth_url
  end

def show
end

  def edit
    user = current_facebook_user.fetch
    @user = User.find_all_by_facebook_id(user.id)
  end

  def update
    user = current_facebook_user.fetch
    @user = User.find_all_by_facebook_id(user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(:first_name => params[:first_name],
                            :last_name => params[:last_name])
      redirect_to user_path, :notice => t('users.update_success')
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

end
```

==========================================================================

The menu is created really well and thanks for this awesome plugin. But when I click edit user I get an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}):
```

Can someone help me with that please? Can someone explain me why in routes.rb resources user only is not working instead of the collection thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of how you are defining the `show` route.

```
resources :users do
    collection do
        get :index
        get :edit
        post :update
        get :show #this is your problem
    end
end
```

Trying renaming this to a different action. The default `show` route is getting overridden.

```
resources :users do
    collection do
        get :index
        get :edit
        post :update
        get :second_show # of course rename this to a better name
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have the same problem. I did what you suggest but still: 2011-06-27T03:10:19+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}):

Comment: can you try this path `<%= link_to user.name, user %>` and make sure `user` is a local variable in the view, or <%= link_to @user.name, @user %>` or however you have access to the user object.

Comment: Can you post how you are generating your link.

Comment: The gem simple-navigation is generating the link with this code:# Configures your navigation

SimpleNavigation::Configuration.run do |navigation|
  navigation.items do |primary|
    primary.item :users, 'Welcome User', root_path do |users|
      users.item :edit, 'Edit Profile', edit_users_path
    end
  end